# Pickadate.js date picker - enable specific weekdays between two dates only

Tags: pickadate

Help required with Pickadate.js:

I'm attempting to enable Mondays to Saturdays (or other day combinations, e.g. Tuesdays and Thursday) within a certain date range (tomorrow until 14 days' time)

I'm sure this is achievable, but have drawn blanks thus far -

```
$('#test').pickadate({
    disable: [
        true,
        //2,3,4,5,6,7,
        { from: [2016,5,16], to: 14 }
    ]
});
```

jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/o7uweL0c/5/

if I uncomment the weekdays (2,3,4,5,6,7), and comment out the { from: [2016,5,16], to: 14 } - I get the right selection of days, but for any dates past or future. The two together don't seem to work.

Sure it's just a syntax thing - any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked this out today - in case anybody needs a pointer!

```
$('#test').pickadate({
    min: true,
    max: 14,
    disable: [
        1, 4, 7
    ]
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o7uweL0c/9/